# Get celery beat trigger time on task

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, celerybeat

I'm trying to find a way to get time time condition that triggered celery beat to fire a task.

Getting `datetime.now()` often deviates from the time at which the task was queued by celery beat due to all celery workers being busy.
For example: I set the task to be executed at 12:30 everyday but due to all workers being busy at the time the task start running at 12:31.

I need to know which time condition triggered to task regardless of the time the task was executed.

EDIT:

This is how I defined my periodic task:

```
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
'periodic_clear_task': {
    'task': 'app.tasks.periodic_clear_task',
    'schedule': crontab(hour=2),
    'args': ()
},
'periodic_update_task': {
    'task': 'app.tasks.periodic_update_task',
    'schedule': crontab(minute='00,30'),
    'args': ()
},
}
```

Comment: You could pass datetime.now() as an argument when you call the task?

Comment: @JensAstrup how can I do that? Edit: I just edited the question to include the definition of my periodic task

Comment: Just remembered that the scheduler is processed once the celery worker is started - not every time it runs the task. In other words, passing the datetime as an argument would only give you the time you started the worker which isn't helpful. It's possible that what you're looking for is available in [bound methods](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#context)

Comment: Hi Leonel, were you able to get this answer? I also want to do the same.

Comment: @MohammadMustaqeem unfortunately not. I ended up queueing those tasks which needed a sharper trigger time in their own queue so they wouldn't have to wait till other tasks finished and that solved my problem. This may not fix the problem in your scenario. It worked for me because those tasks weren't numerous and could be moved to another queue without worrying about sequential execution being lost. If you got any other questions don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: This could become a problem again if the tasks are too heavy, or if you need to use the same queue for some reason (resource use concerns? order of execution concerns?). You could use the same queue for the scheduled tasks, but create a light-weight task-wrapper task with a dedicated queue whose sole responsibility would be to record the current time and launch the scheduled task with this as an arg or kwarg. That being said, nice work-around!

Answer (score 1):

Similar, to the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64064816/3210627) in this question, I have used the expires (seconds) to solve this issue. When using a Celery Beat schedule, it can be specified as follows:

```
limit = 60

CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    ...,

    'periodic_update_task': {
        'task': 'app.tasks.periodic_update_task',
        'schedule': crontab(minute='00,30'),
        'args': (),
        'options': {'expires': 60 * 60 * 24 * limit }
    },
}
```

The limit here is important because since now we're assigning an expiry value, the task wouldn't be executed if this limit is reached. Therefore, it needs to be chosen large enough that the task is processed as necessary. Keep in mind the expiry value is specified in seconds. More information [here](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/calling.html#expiration).

When specifying the expires parameter, Celery automatically converts this seconds value to a datetime value to be used internally. To access the expiration time in the function, you have to bind the method and then retrieve from the task request object. This task object should look something like the one below.

```
<Context: {'lang': 'py', 'task': 'app.tasks.periodic_update_task', 'expires': '2021-10-23T21:11:26.031443+01:00', 'id': 'ef0e301a-b9b3-4930-8fa3-ca3fdf6b36cb', ... }>
```

Once you have that time you can do the simple calculation to re-obtain the trigger time.

```
@app.task(bind=True)
def periodic_update_task(self):
    trigger_time = parser.parse(self.request.expires)-timedelta(days=limit))
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same kind of problem where I wanted to use task trigger time instead of execution time in periodic celery task. I couldn't find the exact field in the celery task which has task trigger time. As a way around I have used expires time of task.

```
task_expires_day =30

@app.on_after_configure.connect
def df_beat_setup(sender, **kwargs):
    pipeline_config = {}
    sender.add_periodic_task(
            crontab(
                    minute=0,
                    hour=8,
            ),
            df_scheduler_task.s(),
            args=(pipeline_config),
            name="df_trigger",
            queue="df_scheduler_queue",
            expires=60*60*24*task_expires_day,
            options={"time": datetime.now()}
    )


@app.task(name="df_scheduler_queue", bind=True, acks_late=True)
def df_scheduler_task(task: "celery.Task", pipeline_config: Dict, time: str) -> dict:
    task_trigger_time = parser.parse(task.request.expires)-timedelta(days=task_expires_day))
    
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

**[after_task_publish](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/signals.html#std-signal-after_task_publish)** signal might be helpful.

## Demo code

```
from django.core.cache import cache
from django.utils import timezone
from celery import Celery
from celery.signals import after_task_publish

app = Celery()
app.conf.beat_schedule = {
    "test-every-minute": {
        "task": "xxx.tasks.test",
        "schedule": 60
    }
}

@after_task_publish.connect
def task_sent_handler(sender=None, headers=None, body=None, **kwargs):
    info = headers if "task" in headers else body
    task_id = info["id"]
    trigger_time = timezone.now()
    cache.set(task_id, trigger_time)  # cache trigger_time
    print(f"task {task_id} sent at {trigger_time}")


@app.task(bind=True)
def test(self):
    execute_time = timezone.now()
    task_id = self.request.id
    print(f"task {task_id} executed at {execute_time}")
    trigger_time = cache.get(task_id)  # get trigger_time
    print(f"task {task_id} triggered at {trigger_time}")
```

## Logs

```
Beat

[2023-07-31 02:17:40,573: INFO/MainProcess] Scheduler: Sending due task test-every-minute (xxx.tasks.test)
[2023-07-31 02:17:40,576: WARNING/MainProcess] task 041af551-01e7-45f8-931f-f3b2fbbad14f sent at 2023-07-31 02:17:40.575942+00:00

Worker

[2023-07-31 02:17:40,582: WARNING/MainProcess] task 041af551-01e7-45f8-931f-f3b2fbbad14f executed at 2023-07-31 02:17:40.582441+00:00
[2023-07-31 02:17:40,585: WARNING/MainProcess] task 041af551-01e7-45f8-931f-f3b2fbbad14f triggered at 2023-07-31 02:17:40.575942+00:00
[2023-07-31 02:17:40,597: INFO/MainProcess] Task rule.tasks.tasks.test[041af551-01e7-45f8-931f-f3b2fbbad14f] succeeded in 0.015511923003941774s: None
```